# How to Highlight C# Syntax from Markdown Text in an MVC3 View

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, syntax-highlighting, markdown

I have an MVC3 web app allowing team members to post and share code snippets. It currently uses PageDown (client-side) and MarkdownSharp (server-side) to handle the text in "markdown" text for persistence. So far so good.

I want to implement syntax highlighting for the C# code rendered from markdown. Anyone know how?

Just to be explicit, I want to do this client-side if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), which is what StackOverflow uses for their syntax highlighting

Comment: I'll check it out, thank you. Gonna leave the question open a little longer and see if other ideas show.